# How to download a file from a website where i have to log in and where the download starts with a javascript form submit?

Tags: javascript, c#, web-scraping

I have to download a file a day from a website. 
I have to log in, go to the download page, insert strings in a form, then click on an "Export" button which starts a js script which submits the form and starts the download. I tried pretty much everything, understood that JS couldn't be handled by the HtmlAgilityPack.

I used ScrapySharp to simulate a web browser. I can log in, go to the export page, click on the button and get the response, but can't handle the download.

Here's my code :

```
public class GetCSVFileTask : BaseTask
{
    ScrapingBrowser Browser;
    public GetCSVFileTask(IStateMachine StateMachine, ITraceEngine Trace, ILogEngine Log)
        : base(StateMachine, Trace, Log)
    {
        this.Log = Log;
        this.Trace = Trace;
        this.stateMachine = StateMachine;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        try
        {
            Init();
            Login();
            DownloadCSV();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write(LogLevel.Error, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Exception: {0}.", ex.ToString()));
        }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
        Browser.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        Browser.AllowMetaRedirect = true;
        Browser.AutoDetectCharsetEncoding = true;
        Browser.AutoDownloadPagesResources = true;
    }
    private void Login()
    {
        var test = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LoginURL"));
        WebPage LoginPage = Browser.NavigateToPage(test);

        var AuthForm = GetAuthForm(LoginPage, Browser);

        AuthForm["Email"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Login");
        AuthForm["Password"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Password");

        AuthForm.Submit();
    }

    private void DownloadCSV()
    {
        WebPage ExportPage = Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ExportURL")));

        PageWebForm DLForm = GetDlForm(ExportPage, Browser);

        WebPage test = DLForm.Submit();
    }

    private PageWebForm GetAuthForm(WebPage loginPage, ScrapingBrowser browser)
    {
        //temp[0] = logout form
        //temp[1] = login form
        var temp = (from n in loginPage.Encoding.GetString(loginPage.RawResponse.Body).ToHtmlNode().Descendants("form")
                    select n).ToList();

        return new PageWebForm(temp[1], browser);
    }
    private PageWebForm GetDlForm(WebPage exportPage, ScrapingBrowser browser)
    {
        //temp[0] = logout form
        //temp[1] = download form
        return GetAuthForm(exportPage, browser);
    }
}
```

The issue I have at the moment is that I don't know how to "catch" the file download and download it in a local folder

Sorry for my bad english, i'm french and new in the developer world :)